# where can I find new themes for SugarCRM? I'm in version 5.2

Tags: themes, sugarcrm

I would like to download new themes for sugar crm...I have looked for it in internet but I haven't found any link where I can download themes. Can you help to me? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you just make them yourself, either starting from scratch or customizing the existing themes ([Documentation](http://developers.sugarcrm.com/docs/OS/5.2/-docs-Developer_Guides-Developer_Guide_5.2-DevGuide%205.2.1.50.html)).

It is possible to download some themes, but they usually require some (minor) changes, due to SugarCRM version differences:

- http://www.sugarforge.org/softwaremap/trove_list.php?form_cat=335
- http://www.crmthemeclub.com/en/

Answer (score 0):

For developing your own theme this GitHub project by Epicom is a great starting point: [Epicom/Google theme](https://github.com/Epicom/GoogleTheme)

If you aren't looking to make your own theme for SugarCRM check out the themes available here: [SugarOutfitters Themes](https://www.sugaroutfitters.com/sugarcrm-themes/). So far the [Google Style SugarTheme](https://www.sugaroutfitters.com/addons/google-style-sugartheme) has been the most popular. However, [EasyTheme](https://www.sugaroutfitters.com/addons/easytheme) has some nice built in basic reporting features.